# CASE WHEN with FOR and IN Functions SQL

Tags: sql, case, cognos

I need some help with adding a function to an expression in Cognos. I have the following working...

```
CASE WHEN
[Current Description]='Testing' THEN 'Invited to Test'

WHEN [Current Description]<>'Rejected' AND 'Testing' IN ([Student History Description])
THEN 'Invited to Test'
ELSE ''
END
```

I need to basically add a "FOR x" statement into it so that the expression only checks the test description applicable "FOR x". Currently it checks the student's entire history. Let's call it [Test Code] and variables would be like SAT,GRE,MCAT. I'd want the code to be something like:

```
CASE WHEN
    [Current Description]='Testing' THEN 'Invited to Test'
    WHEN [Current Description]<>'Rejected' AND 'Testing' IN ([Student History Description] FOR [Test Code])
    THEN 'Invited to Test'
    ELSE ''
    END
```

Comment: Just so you know, `'Testing' IN ([Student History Description])` is the same as `'Testing' = [Student History Description]`.

Comment: What logical function is "FOR x" supposed to serve?   The only "FOR" use I know of is in setting up a loop.   Or specifying a type of trigger.

Comment: "FOR x" isn't a real function, more like what I'm trying to solve... I need it to restrict the range of the case statement to the results for a specific test code. Currently, the expression gives me results for all test results in a student's history. I'd like it to say: When the current description is not rejected and testing is found in the student description history "FOR the relevant test tied to the application" then tell me that the student was invited to test.

Comment: Does [Test Code] exist in the same row as all of the other data items mentioned? Can you provide a psuedo code description of what you want so we can understand the logic you desire?